# no output,I have make a program to find all armstrong no.between 100 to 1000

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a,b,c,d;
    c=0;
    for(a=100;a<1000;a++) {
        for(b=a;b>0;b=b/10) {
           d=b%10;
           c=c+d*d*d;
        }
        if(c==a) {
            cout<<c<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize `c` before each check.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    c=0;
    for(a=100;a<1000;a++)
    {
        c=0; // add this
        for(b=a;b>0;b=b/10)
        {
            d=b%10;
            c=c+d*d*d;
        }
        if(c==a)
        {
            cout<<c<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```